# Bash_profile for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I recently updated my "bash_profile" and I'm assuming I deleted/overwritten something.

When I'm trying to run my rails app with "rails s" command, it says

```
-bash: /mnt/c/Ruby30-x64/bin/rails: C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Anyone that could share their "bash_profile" 's content would probably fix my issue.
I'm hoping this is the case.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't magically fix this by copying soem arbitrary bash profile, so even I sent you mine, it wouldn't help you at all. You have to track down the error: So first question: Where is your `ruby.exe` located?

Comment: @user1934428 when I checked my environment variables, the rails files are found under /mnt/c/Ruby30-x64/bin . Is this what you were looking for? Although on the directory, it doesn't have the "ruby.exe"

Comment: Can this be referenced on your platform by `C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/ruby.exe` and is this a  working Ruby version? I.e. does `C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/ruby.exe --version` output something reasonable?

Comment: @user1934428 Oh wait, ruby.exe is on this directory. It returned the Ruby version 3.0.0p. Am I missing something that "rails s" command doesn't work on the app directory anymore?

Comment: Did you execute **exactly** the command I was sending to you, from inside the bash shell (copy and paste)?

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, I did that but I'm on Ubuntu. I went for /mnt/c/Ruby30-x64/bin/ruby.exe --version and it showed the ruby version.

Comment: @user1934428 but when I run the "rails server" command on the ruby app path, it returns still the error -bash: /mnt/c/Ruby30-x64/bin/rails: C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter: No such file or directory. On my User variables, I still have C:\Ruby30-x64\bin under "Path".

Comment: I did not say in my comment that you should type `/mnt/c/....` ; I said you should type `C:/....`. Please read the comments carefully, and do a copy&paste, to avoid typing errors!

Comment: @Musashiori are you on Ubuntu or you are using wsdl in windows?